# Installing amsynth LV2 for use with Ardour 5

Tags: 18.04, plugins, ardour

Trying to install the LV2 Plugin for amsynth synthesizer. I'd like to use it directly in Ardour 5.

Simply installing through the standard repository doesn't help, though.

```
sudo apt-get install amsynth
```

The plugin is not listed under /usr/lib/lv2 ... while the calf plugin is there and working.

Do I need to add kxstudio repository or manually add the directory? I've trial and errored for some hours, now. Thanks!

---

Please note:
 - Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
 - Ardour5.12.0 (built using 1:5.12.0-3 and GCC version 7.3.0)

Comment: Right, `lv2` is not directly under `/usr/lib`, it's in a subdirectory. Please study [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/amsynth/filelist) which shows which files the `amsynth` package installs on an `amd64` architecture.

Comment: Thank you ... that's right. I found the amsynth plugin here `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lv2/amsynth.lv2/` which actually is not a directory, Ardour 5 scans for plugins.

Comment: Well, I suspect that you wouldn't have stumbled upon that issue if you had installed `ardour` from the Ubuntu archive. The info about which directories it scans makes me think that the default configuration of the upstream software is made with Fedora in mind without thinking of Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh, the info about the directories is taken from the source listed in the answer. afaik I've installed ardour from the Ubuntu archive ;) -- Ardour Version 1:5.12.0-3, Source ubuntu-bionic-universe

Comment: Really? In that case I'd say that it's a bug. Packages from the Ubuntu archive should reasonably be compatible with each other without the kind of tweaking you had to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is how I manged to install and activate amsynth as an LV2 for use with Ardour 5 (on `amd64` architecture):

Step 1: install **amsynth** through repositories

```
sudo apt-get install amsynth
```

Step 2: copy **amsynth** plugin to a directory Ardour 5 actually scans for example (see sidenote):

```
sudo cp -r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lv2/amsynth.lv2/ /usr/lib/lv2/
```

Step 3: add/drag **amsynth** to your midi lane through Ardours' plugin manager

[image: add amsynth to midi lane in Ardour 5]

Have fun composing!

---

Sidenotes:

Directories that are scanned for plugins:
~/.lv2:/usr/local/lib/lv2:/usr/local/lib64/lv2:/usr/lib/lv2:/usr/lib64/lv2 (Source: Paul David https://discourse.ardour.org/t/calf-plugins-cannot-be-loaded/90426/9)

**amsynth** is also installed as a standalone application. It can be launched independently from Ardour or Jack. There you can find features like random settings etc.